# How to get a variable value by passing pageName and variableName in a function

Tags: java, selenium

I am using a page object model. So each page file contains variables(element). I call the function to click on element by passing the pageName and variableName.

page:

```
public class ChangeNamePageAndroid {
        @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@text='First name']")
        public MobileElement firstNameLbl;
    }
```

Here 'firstNameLbl' is the varibleName (MobileElement)

function definition:

```
import com.example.pageobjects.ChangeNamePageAndroid;

public class ChangeNameUtilAndroid{

public ChangeNamePageAndroid changeNamePageAndroid = new ChangeNamePageAndroid();

public void enter123(String pageName, String mobileElementTitle, String text) {
   // **MobileElement mobileElement = pageName.mobileElementTitle;**
      mobileElement.sendKeys(text);
      }
    }
```

How to get the element from another page?

here I pass pageName and variableName while calling the function.

```
enter123(ChangeNamePageAndroid, firstNameLbl);
```

Note: I have done a similar thing in javascript

```
clickButton: function(pageName,varibleName){
    var page = require(pageName+'.js');
    var x = page[varibleName];
    element(by.id(x)).click();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see in this commented line, you are trying to click on static field.
 **MobileElement mobileElement = pageName.mobileElementTitle;**

So that you need to static mobile elements in your page class (changeName...class).

OR

Add getters function to return page elements in the same class where your elements located.

I suggest to use factory data structure to make elements factory classes.

@FindBy/@AndroidFindBy called page factory, in order to use page object model you need to add real names to elements and functions in you page class.

For example: 
class Login should include at least 3 elements named: usernameElement, passwordElement and loginButton.
The functions must describe the real action: 
public void clickLoginButton().